# cut / grep df -h

Tags: linux, text-processing, disk-usage, columns

How can I get the mount point "3.1T" under the column " Avail" (using grep or cut)?

```
Filesystem                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

vstorage://cluster07                  4.0T  907G  3.1T  23% /vstorage/cluster07
```

Answer (score 8):

Tell `df` what to output:

```
df -h --output=avail | tail -n1
```

> Note: this might not be portable to all *nixes.

Answer (score 6):

Use `awk`

```
awk '{print $4}'
3.1T  

 echo vstorage://cluster07                  4.0T  907G  3.1T  23% /vstorage/cluster07 | awk '{print $4}'
```

or `grep`

```
 grep -o '\b3.1T\b'
 3.1T  

 echo vstorage://cluster07                  4.0T  907G  3.1T  23% /vstorage/cluster07 | grep -o '\b3.1T\b'


\b in a regular expression means "word boundary".
-o, --only-matching
```

or `cut`:

```
cut -d" " -f4
 3.1T  

 echo vstorage://cluster07                  4.0T  907G  3.1T  23% /vstorage/cluster07 | cut -d" " -f4
```

Note that, practically, you would need to convert your table to a fixed-widths table, then use `cut` as follows:

```
echo "vstorage://cluster07                  4.0T  907G  3.1T  23% /vstorage/cluster07" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { printf "%-5s",$i } ; printf("\n"); }' | cut -d" " -f3
3.1T
```

Comment: Third example (`grep`) works only for hardcoded values. I don't belive OP wants that. And also, if we're going to use hardcoded values, `grep -o 3.1T` is more than enough.

Comment: If you try with the actual output from `df`, or with the argument to `echo` properly quoted, you'll see that `cut` doesn't work here. It takes each space as a column separator, while `awk` by default considers consecutive sets of whitespace as one separator

Comment: If you're going to use `grep` that way, you might as well simplify it to `echo '3.1T'`!

Answer (score 3):

try the below command,

```
df -h | awk '/\/vstorage\/cluster07/ {print $4}'
```

Comment: Awk can match regular expressions just fine: `awk '/\/vstorage\/cluster07/ {print $4}'` or better yet `awk '$6=="/vstorage/cluster07" {print $4}'`. No need to involve Grep *in addition*.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
df -h | sed -rn 's|[^ ]+ +([^ ]+) .*|\1|p'
```

Or, with `grep`:

```
df -h | grep -Eo '[0-9]+%'
```

The last one may be a bit crude because it depends on exactly one `%` character in the ouput of `df -h`. But it's quite simple and effective.

Comment: For the given input, your first command gives `4.0T` and your second one gives `23%`.  (Neither is correct.)